# how to send picture through email if we having a picture in base64 format in android?

Tags: android

i want to send picture with message through email and I also want to show that picture in my email body.,i have tried this code but it is not working ,what i do.here is  My code:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(getFileStreamPath( "<img src=data:image/*;base64,#mediaUrlBase64#\">"));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

here is the photo:-[image]

thankyou...:)

Answer (score 1):

**Tried:**

I had used **bold tag** and **anchor tag** as i shown below these tag are working fine , but when i used **img tag** i can able to see a square box which say as OBJ:

```
 i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml("<b>Hi</b><a href='http://www.google.com/'>Link</a> <img src='http://url/to/the/image.jpg'>",
    imgGetter,
    null));
i.setType("image/png");
```

And also tried this:

```
"<img src=\"http://images.anandtech.com/doci/3982/HTCSurround-0134.jpg\">"
```

But no luck. I found some answer from SO and found that unfortunately, it's not possible to do this with Intents.

The reason why for example **bold** text is displayed in the EditText and not an Image is that [StyleSplan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StyleSpan.html) is implementing [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) whereas [ImageSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html) does not. So when the Intent.EXTRA_TEXT is retrieved in the new Activity the ImageSpan will fail to unparcel and therefore not be part of the style appended to the EditText.

Using other methods where you don't pass the data with the Intent is unfortunately not possible here as you're not in control of the receiving Activity.